# Using YouTube editor to trim clips longer than 15 minutes

Tags: youtube

I wanted to transfer some videos across to YouTube the other day and forgot two of them went over the 15 minute limit. So they were rejected, no problem with that (ended up splitting the clips then uploading once more).

Then today I stumbled across [YouTube.com/Editor](http://www.youtube.com/editor) which allows one to :

- Combine multiple videos you’ve uploaded to create a new longer video
- Trim at the beginning and / or ending of your videos
- Add a soundtrack from our AudioSwap library
- Create new videos

Looking in my [videos](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos) section, I see the rejected videos are still there (or at least the info that they were rejected still shows). The only option available seems to be delete with no chance of replacing the video. So what could be the reason for not letting the system just delete it (or better, allow me to use their editor to trim it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube now allows user to upload videos greater than 15 minutes; but it was not so a long time ago (when you tried uploading those videos).

For reasons known only to Google and YouTube developers, the info (Title of the Video, Description, Date and Time of Upload, and may be even a Screenshot of the Video) of the videos that failed to get uploaded to YouTube (due to longer duration or unproper file format)(or were uploaded but later removed due to Copyright Violation)(or were later deleted by the up-loader itself); still remains in the User's accounts and only the particular User and the site's moderators/administrators can see them. If a link for the video was generated and anyone happens to visit the link, there would be a message saying that the **Link is invalid** or **Video is deleted** or **Video removed due to Copyright Violation** or something like that.

You cannot Combine, Trim or add soundtrack to those videos as they were never uploaded at all, or deleted or were uploaded and still are available with Youtube but no one has access to them as someone filled a Copyright Violation Complain and Claimed it to be their property.